# How-to Form confirmation response

Tags: laravel

I am a Laravel newbie. I have gone through tutorials successfully...this is my first production app for a client, using Laravel

I have a form and am able to get the submitted data into a database. The user is given a generic error though. After successful submission, I cannot redirect the user to a confirmation page. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code from my controller (the store function):

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    $rules = array(
        'lastname'       => 'required',
        'email'      => 'required|email',
        'phone' => 'required',
        'date' => 'date|date_format:"m/d/Y"'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // process the login
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('nerds/create')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    }
    else
    {
        // store
        $registration = new Registration;
        $registration->firstname       = Input::get('firstname');
        $registration->lastname       = Input::get('lastname');
        $registration->email      = Input::get('email');
        $registration->date       = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(Input::get('date')));
        $registration->phone      = Input::get('phone');
        $registration->venue       = Input::get('venue');
        $registration->venueCity       = Input::get('venueCity');
        $registration->save();

        // redirect
        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully submitted, someone will contact you soon!');
        return Redirect::to('thankyou');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some error messages?

Comment: Its the basic error, the only one I have seen in Laravel - "Whoops, Looks like something went wrong"

Comment: You code looks good, are you sure `store()` method is called.

Comment: Go to app/config/app.php, set 'debug' as true. Then you can see complete error messages.

Comment: edisonthk - yes. Without the redirect, the data is stored in the DB.

Comment: 尤川豪 Wow! The debug setting is a huge help! With it I found that I did not have the full path in my redirect, I got a 'not found' error. Ichanged the return to :
return Redirect::to('registration/thankyou')
I now get no errors, a blank page instead.

Comment: can u call the route manually?

Comment: nozzleman - I cannot. I still get a blank page

Comment: All - I found the answer and posted it. Thanks so much for all the help. You definitely live up to the helpful nature reputation of the Laravel community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a route to handle the 'Redirect::to'
The tutorial I followed failed to mention this fact.

Along with the code from my controller's store() function, the following route is necessary.

```
Route::get('/registration/thankyou', function()
{
    return View::make('thankyou');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the app/storage folder has the full permissions. Apache should be able to write to that folder.